# Is it normal that it is a lot of work (sometimes doesn't work at all) to import projects from github etc. to the own IDE

Tags: github, intellij-idea, import, ide, project

When there are github projects, especially Java with GUI (JavaFx/ Java Swing) it is a lot of work to open and run it in the own IDE. I use IntelliJ and when I open projects I have to add a configuration to run it. There you have to select the main class but it's often impossible to select the class which is the main class of the project. I tried "mark folder as source" but that leads to errors too.
I just want to know if that is normal or if I am doing something wrong. Are there any tips?

Comment: Different projects require different configuration (arguments, options etc) to run. It can be a web application, a console based application, a service oriented application so IDEA can`t know what type of application you imported. It is really common that you have to add your own configuration.

Comment: This really depends on the project. Many projects use some type of build/dependency tool (i.e. Maven), which IntelliJ can import and "preconfigure" for you and you can "just" start working.